# How to charm-like effects that do not affect charm immune creatures interact with Fey Ancestry?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, charmed

In *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* (pg. 189), the Duergar Mind Master has the following Mind Mastery action:

> ***Mind Mastery.*** The duergar targets one creature it can see within 60 feet. The target must succeed on a DC 12 Intelligence saving throw, or the duergar causes it to use its reaction either to make one weapon attack against another creature the duergar can see or to move up to 10 feet in a direction of the duergar's choice. **Creatures that can't be charmed are immune to this effect**.

An elf has the Fey Ancestry racial feature, listed in the PHB (pg. 23):

> ***Fey Ancestry.*** You have **advantage on saving throws against being charmed**, and magic can't put you to sleep.

Mind Mastery does not specifically say that it charms its target, which is to say, imposes the "charmed" condition. However, it does call out that creatures who are immune to charm effects are immune to this effect as well.

So what of elves, or other creatures who have advantage against saving throws to charm effects? Would this apply here due to the fact that creatures immune to charm effects aren't affected, or does it not apply because it's not specifically "being charmed"?